# Scrapy Spider not returning any results

Tags: hyperlink, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to build a scraper with Scrapy. My overall goal is to scrape the webpages of a website and return a list of links for all downloadable documents of the different pages.

Somehow my code does return only None. I am not sure what the cause for this could be. Thank you for your help in advance. Please note that the robots.txt does not cause this issue.

```
import re
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from w3lib.url import url_query_cleaner

def processlinks(links):
    for link in links:
        link.url = url_query_cleaner(link.url)
        yield link

class ExampleCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    start_urls = ["https://example.com/"] 
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                deny=[
                    re.escape('https://www.example.com/offsite'),
                    re.escape('https://www.example.com/whitelist-offsite'),
                ],
            ),
            process_links=processlinks,
            callback='parse_links',
            follow=False
        ),)


    def parse_links(self, response):
        html = response.body

       
        links = scrapy.Selector(text=html).xpath('//@href').extract()

       
        documents = []
        for link in links:
            absolute_url = urljoin(response.url, link)
            documents.append(absolute_url)

       
        return documents
```

I expected to receive a list containing all document download links for all webpages of the website. I only got a None value returned. It seems like that parse_links method does not get called.

Answer (score 1):

There were a few logical and technical issues in the code. I have made changes to the code. Below are the details.

Your site was redirecting to another site so you need to update the allowed domains and added [www.iana.org](http://www.iana.org) to it.

```
allowed_domains = ['www.example.com', 'www.iana.org']
```

Secondly, in scrapy, you can't return a list or string it should be a request or team in the form or dictionary. see the last time code.

```
import re
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from w3lib.url import url_query_cleaner
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import scrapy

def processlinks(links):
    for link in links:
        link.url = url_query_cleaner(link.url)
        yield link

class ExampleCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com', 'www.iana.org']
    start_urls = ["https://example.com/"] 
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                deny=[
                    re.escape('https://www.example.com/offsite'),
                    re.escape('https://www.example.com/whitelist-offsite'),
                ],
            ),
            process_links=processlinks,
            callback='parse_links',
            follow=False
        ),)


    def parse_links(self, response):
        html = response.body

       
        links = scrapy.Selector(text=html).xpath('//@href').extract()

       
        documents = []
        for link in links:
            absolute_url = urljoin(response.url, link)
            documents.append(absolute_url)

       
        return {"document": documents}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ikram Khan Niazi. Please excuse my very late reply.